# to add button which will redirect to View Page of current row in JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to add button instead of `View` column but i tried with `formatter` still button is not loading but records are coming for the rest of the columns.
Below is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Location/LocationsList1",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Country Name', 'State Name', 'City Name', 'Location Name','View'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'CountryName', index: 'CountryName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'StateName', index: 'StateName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'CityName', index: 'CityName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Name', index: 'Name', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'View', index: 'View', editable: true,formatter:ViewButton }],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Location',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },

    });
});
function ViewButton(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var rowid= options.rowid;
    var button = "<button class=\"viewLineItem\" id="+ rowid+">View Line   Item</button>"
    $('#' + rowid).die();
    $('#' + rowid).live('click', function (rowId) {
        alert("hi");
        alert(rowId);
    });
};
```

I am new to JqGrid and don't know how it works. Any guidance/Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has some problems

1. `options` has no `rowid` property, but it has `rowId` property. You should change `options.rowid` to `options.rowId`
2. The formatter will be called **during building the HTML fragment of the grid body**. No element of the grid exist at the moment on the page. Thus you can't use `$('#' + rowid).live('click', ...);` at the moment.
3. The formatter have to return the HTML fragment, which will be placed in the corresponding cell (inside of `<td>`). One misses `return button;` at the end of the formatter.
4. There are exist well-known name conversion in JavaScript. One should use functions, which starts with capital letter only if you define the constructor of the new class. You see that `ViewButton` will be displayed in the other color to distinguish classes from other function. You should rename `ViewButton` to `viewButton` to hold the standard name conversion of JavaScript.
5. It's better don't specify `index` property in `colModel`. In the same way one should not include the properties with the defaul value, like `key: false`. To specify *common* property for many columns you can use `cmTemplate` property.
6. One should reduce the number of **global** functions, because the functions will be considerd as the properties of `window` object.
7. instead of usage hidden column with `name: 'Id'` one can specify `id: 'Id'` property of `jsonReader`. You use `repeatitems: false` property, which means that every item of input data has properties `CountryName`, `StateName` and so on. The default name of the id property (the rowid - the `id` of `<tr>` elements) is `id`, but you use `Id` instead. The property `id: "Id"` informs jqGrid about it.

The modified code could be about the following

```
$(function () {
    function viewButton(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return "<button class=\"viewLineItem\" id=\"" +
            options.rowId + "\">View Line   Item</button>";
    }

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Location/LocationsList1",
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Country Name', 'State Name', 'City Name', 'Location Name','View'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Id', key: true, hidden: true },
            { name: 'CountryName' },
            { name: 'StateName' },
            { name: 'CityName' },
            { name: 'Name' },
            { name: 'View', editable: false, formatter: viewButton }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { editable: true },
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Location',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "Id" }
    });

    $("#jqGridA").click(function (e) {
        var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
            rowid = $td.parent().attr("id"),
            p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");

        if ($td.length > 0 && p.colModel[$td[0].cellIndex].name === "View") {
            alert(rowid);
        }
    });
});
```

The last part of the above code (`$("#jqGridA").click(...);`) register **one** click handler for the whole grid. If the user clicks on any cell then the event handler will be called because of [event bubbling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Event_flow). The `e.target` gives as the DOM element, which was clicked (for example the `<button>`). By using `closest` we can go to the outer `<td>` element, which parent is the row (`<tr>`) of the grid. The `.attr("id")` of the row is the rowid. Such binding works more effectively as binding click handler to **every** button inside of the grid.

By the way jqGrid has already one `click` event handler. One can use `beforeSelectRow` callback, because it will be called inside of the `click` handler. One should only don't forget to return `true` from the `beforeSelectRow` callback to inform jqGrid that you allow to select the row. The callback `beforeSelectRow` has already `rowid` as the first parameter, which simplify our code a little. The final code will be

```
$(function () {
    function viewButton(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return "<button class=\"viewLineItem\" id=\"" +
            options.rowId + "\">View Line   Item</button>";
    }

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/Location/LocationsList1",
        datatype: 'json',
        colNames: ['Id', 'Country Name', 'State Name', 'City Name', 'Location Name','View'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'CountryName' },
            { name: 'StateName' },
            { name: 'CityName' },
            { name: 'Name' },
            { name: 'View', editable: false, formatter: viewButton }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { editable: true },
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Location',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "Id" },
        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
            var $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
                p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");

            if ($td.length > 0 && p.colModel[$td[0].cellIndex].name === "View") {
                alert(rowid);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg..That works great..Do you have any idea about implementing sorting and searching in grid without ajax post call to controller in JQGrid

Comment: @Steve: You are welcome! The server should just return the array of **all** items (from `url`) and you should add `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. In case of usage my fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)) you can use additionally `forceClientSorting: true` option, which allows to sort (by `sortname` and `sortorder`) and to filter (by `postData.filters`) the data returned from the server **before** the first page of returned data is displayed. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) as an example.

Comment: @Steve: The performance of **local** paging, sorting and filtering is very good. You can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) how much time takes sorting, filtering or paging of the grid with 40000 rows, 13 columns displayed in 20 rows per page.

Comment: `loadonce:true` works for me.Thanks for that..but for this i have to load all the data at once..actually i was trying to use `.ToPagedList` in my query but it was returning only first 10 records and as the pager was disabled to fetch 2nd page of 10 records so not able to work with pager in this case :(

Comment: @Steve: I don't full understand your problem. How many totally rows should be displayed in the grid? You can see in my last comment that 1000 or 40000 rows can be loaded and filtered quickly enough. Why loading of all the data is the problem? If you have really a lot of data (millions of items) then you have to implement **server side paging, sorting and filtering**. Displaying unfiltered data in the grid (the first 20 from 10 millions) gives the user no practical information. `.ToPagedList` is unclear for me. It you have server side problems you should open new question with the C# code.